# How to use GS_THREADSAFE option for invoking Ghostscript API

Tags: multithreading, ghostscript

Am using Ghostscript API for converting PDF to Image(Tiff) using C#, but only one instance at a time is supported.

if Ghostscript is compiled with the GS_THREADSAFE define then multiple concurrent instances are permitted.
documentation: http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/API.htm

Kindly assist me, how i can invoke GhostScript APi with GS_THREADSAFE option.
Any sample code is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand your question. You compile Ghostscript with the GS_THREADSAFE compiler definition. Then you can call gs_api_new_instance() as many times as you require separate instances.

Each instance can be fed a different input.

Its not obvious to me why you would bother having multiple instances though.

Comment: Ken, i am using this PDF to tiff conversion in mutlithread windowservice application.say, when my 1st thread start processing 55 pages PDF document, in meanwhile if another thread started tries to create instance of the Ghost script then am getting error.

Comment: Well, then you need to give the error, its not really possible to say much without that.

Comment: am getting -101 errorcode, as soon as i start 2nd instance of ghostscript API.
used code from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32274/How-To-Convert-PDF-to-Image-Using-Ghostscript-API?msg=3589191

Comment: What happens if you create 2 instances without statrting one.

Comment: it works good as i have only ONE instance of ghostscript API now. Problem occurs when the 1st instance is processing the PDf, and another request came and we try to create an instance for it.please check here http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/API.htm section. 3.2 gsapi_new_instance()  
Historically, Ghostscript has only supported a single instance; any attempt to create more than one at a time would result in gsapi_new_instance returning an error. Experimental work has been done to lift this restriction; if Ghostscript is compiled with the GS_THREADSAFE

Comment: It sounds like you haven't recompiled Ghostscript with the GS_THREADSAFE define. The only way to tell is to run it under a debugger and look at the code.

Comment: Yes, i don't know how to recompile Ghostscript with the GS_THREADSAFE define.Could you please let me know to compile with GS_THREADSAFE

Comment: It depends totally on the operating system you are using. You should refer to /ghostpdl/gs/doc/make.htm. Once you can build Ghostscript, then you can add the GS_THREADSAFE compiler definition to the makefile/solution/project